# Pros and cons of different branching models in DVCS

Tags: git, mercurial, branch, bazaar

The Big Three of distributed version control (Git, Bazaar, and Mercurial) each treat branching fairly differently. In Bazaar, for example, branches are separate repos (actually, divergent copies of the parent repo); on your file system, different branches live in different directories. In Git, on the other hand, you can have multiple branches existing in the same repo (and therefore in the same directory on your file system). Mercurial supports [both behaviors](http://stevelosh.com/blog/entry/2009/8/30/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/), the latter with [named branches](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html#id386031).

What are the pros and cons associated with these different branching models? In my mind, Bazaar's approach of one branch, one repo makes branching more of a pain than Git's approach (e.g. to use a branch in Bazaar, I have to first create the branch, then cd out of my current working copy, then check out the new branch, like I would in SVN).

Comment: named branches is quite different from git branches, see here for details: http://stevelosh.com/blog/entry/2009/8/30/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/

Comment: See also my answer in "Git and Mercurial - Compare and Contrast", which covers also branches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598759/git-and-mercurial-compare-and-contrast/1599930#1599930

Comment: Man, tonfa always manages to post my blog entry before I do!  :)

Answer (score 10):

Bazaar doesn't require you to work the way you describe. I've actually written [a blog post](http://oxygene.sk/lukas/2009/10/working-with-branches-in-bazaar/) about it two days ago. You can work pretty much with only a single working tree, switching between various branches and creating new branches without leaving the working tree. Useful commands for this are: [`checkout`](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-reference/index.html#checkout), [`switch`](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-reference/index.html#switch), [`branch --switch`](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-reference/index.html#branch). Check out the [workflow](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-guide/bazaar_workflows.html) documentation for Bazaar, you will see that you can configure it in almost any way you want.

Comment: It's good to know that Bazaar is more flexible than I thought. I was actually wondering if creating a "branches" directory inside your repo could solve the problem I mentioned in my question. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know much about branching models in VCS other than Git.  I'd say that in any DVCS you can implement branching by cloning (you create a branch by doing a clone).  Mercurial so-called "named branches" are (from what I understand it) in fact *commit labels* only interpreted as a branch, sometimes requiring local numbering of revisions to resolve ambiguity.  Mercurial "bookmarks" ar, I think, quite similar to Git branches.  The two DVCS that have *very* different concept of branching are [Monotone](http://monotone.ca) and [Darcs](http://www.darcs.net).  I think that "branching by copying" that Subversion uses, where separation between project name and branch name is by *convention*, is a wrong idea.

---

In Git revisions form a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of commits.  It is directed, because commits have parents.  That is a very important issue: edges in DAG of commits are from commit to its parent (or, in the case of merge commit, two or more its parents).  Graph of commits is acyclic, which means that there is no chain (no path) that begins and ends with the same object.

[Git glossary](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) defines "branch" as an **active line of development**.  This idea is behind an implementation of branches in Git.

The most recent  commit on a branch is referred to as the **tip** of that branch. The tip of the branch is referenced by a **branch head**, which is just a symbolic name for this commit.  In its "loose" form such branch head (for example for branch named 'master') is just a file somewhere in `refs/heads/` directory inside git repository (inside `.git` dir), which contains reference to current tip of a branch: its SHA-1 identifier of commit (as hexadecimal string).

When you create a new commit in Git, the tip of currently checked out branch moves forward.  In other words the new commit is created on top of tip of current branch, and branch head advances to the new commit (somewhat similarly to how the pointer to top of stack might advance).

A single git repository can track an arbitrary number of branches, but your working tree (if you have any) is associated with just one of them (the "current" or "checked out" branch).  Current branch is given by the HEAD pointer.  HEAD is (usually) pointer to currently checked out branch (to a branch head name), just like branch heads are pointers to tips of branches.

For example if currently checked out branch is 'master', then `.git/HEAD` file (representing HEAD) would contain single LF terminated line with `ref: refs/heads/master` (a symbolic reference to `refs/heads/master`), and `.git/refs/heads/master` (head of 'master' branch) would contain for example LF terminated line `0b127cb8ab975e43398a2b449563ccb78c437255`, whihc is SHA-1 identifier to tip of 'master' branch (that is if current branch is not "packed": then you have to take a look at `.git/packed-refs`).

Some commands in Git, such as "git commit" or "git reset" manipulate / change branch head; other such as "git checkout" manipulate / change HEAD (symbolic reference to current branch).

"`git log branch`" command shows all commit reachable from branch tip, which means tip of branch, its parent, parent (or parents) of that parent commit etc.  It shows part of a DAG of commits.

In Git deleting a branch means simply removing a branch head.  That might mean that some commits become "invisible", unreachable freom refs (branches and tags), which means that at some time those commits could get garbage collected and removed from repository. But if you can delete branch with "git branch -d <branchname>" then that means that no commits would be lost; you can force branch deletion with "git branch -D <branchname>".  Renaming a branch is simply a matter of renaming branch head, a symbolic reference (symbolic name) of branch tip; branch names are not saved anywhere in the commit object.

---

Git has also concept of ***reflogs***, which is a local history of where branch tip pointed (and when).  For example if you amend a commit with "git commit --amend", branch tip would get replaced with amended commit, and HEAD^ would be parent of commit before and after amending, while there would be entry in reflog for version before amending and after amending.  If you rewind history using "git reset", reflog would contain information of old branch tip before rewinding.

In short reflog gives additional safety and easy recovery to git commands.