# A working directory for every branch

Tags: git

My typical workday involves reviewing other devs' code and fixing multiple bugs at once. Are there any methodologies to quickly checkout a branch without having to interrupt your work in the current branch?

I do this many times per day and frequently forget which step I'm on.

1. `git stash`
2. `git checkout feature-b`
3. `git pull`

   ... make some commits, etc ...
4. `git push`
5. `git checkout feature-a`
6. `git stash pop`

Edit: Multiple directories are cool, but I don't think it's necessarily the only way to solve this.

Comment: That seems like the typical stash-based workflow many people use. I'm not sure what you mean by "frequently forget which step I'm on"?

Comment: @jingx It's another workflow that I have to keep in my working memory. I'd rather spend my brain resources on the problems I'm solving.

Comment: Well, if you mean you don't want to remember which branch you were on, I suppose you could do local clones of the same repo, each having one branch checked out. But then you still gotta remember which _directory_ you were in, instead of branch, so we are back to square one...

Comment: @jingx That's interesting.

Comment: If your Git is too old (pre 2.5), consider the multiple clone solution @jingx mentions. Note that local clones share underlying data storage, at least initially (eventually they grow apart). If you have `git worktree add`, that's probably the way to go; there you're literally sharing the underlying repository, so there are fewer disk-space issues and synchronization is automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Store branches in separate local directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101270/git-store-branches-in-separate-local-directories)

Comment: It might not be the *only* way, but it is the best way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better workflow would be to use the [`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309), which allows you to checkout different branches (of the same repo cloned only once) in different folders.

That way, no more stash to do, only a pull in the right folder.
You current work in a given branch remains untouched, unmodified, while you are doing a review in another folder/branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- Save all work
- Make a `Work In Progress` commit
- Switch branches

I don't trust stashes enough to save work in them. I might just save a local config setting or something that isn't critical.