# Auditing code moving across files with git

Tags: git

This may not be what git is designed for - which I can accept - but I'm curious if this is possible, seeing as it comes up alot for me.

**Scenario: A developer moves method X from file A to file B (both existing tracked files). I want to know if they also *changed method X on copy***

Now, if I use gitk to inspect file B, I can see the introduction of the method. The issue is that I want to know if the method was simply copy/pasted, or also modified in the process.

My gut says that this information is lost, but is there a way I can reverse engineer which file method X was copied from using git?

I.e. Solve for file A using git. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Git really track the movement of a single function from 1 file to another? If so, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908336/can-git-really-track-the-movement-of-a-single-function-from-1-file-to-another-i)

Comment: Thanks, looks like `git blame -C` is the answer. I'll answer this for a quick answer, and link back to that for verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

`git blame -C` is the command to use.

Here is [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame.html), and [a near duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908336/can-git-really-track-the-movement-of-a-single-function-from-1-file-to-another-i) (how does it work? vs what do I use?) with a more verbose answer.