# How to do git-rebase with a sparse checkout?

Tags: git, git-rebase, sparse-checkout

I have a working copy with a sparse checkout enabled. And I want to do the `git rebase -i`. But if I get conflict while rebasing all of the excluded from checkout files are marked as `deleted` and `not staged for commit`.

So, when I do resolve real conflicts and `git add` required files, I still can't do `git rebase --continue` due to unstaged changes. I can do `git checkout -f -- <excluded files>`, but it's very inconvenient.

Is there a better way to `git-rebase` with a sparse checkout?

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in "[Git sparse checkout with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309)", you now have the [`git sparse-checkout` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout).
By "now", I mean since Git 2.25+ (Q1 2020).

And, as I documented in "[How to disable sparse checkout after enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36195275/6309)", you can disable / re-enable a sparse checkout.

Since rebasing with a sparse-checkout is tricky (because the rebase operation works on the entire history and not just the files you have in your working directory), you can consider that disable/enable approach (with a more recent Git version than the 2015 one):

```bash
git branch backup-branch
git sparse-checkout disable
git rebase -i <base-branch>

# Resolve them as you normally would.
# After resolving, stage the changes: 
git add <resolved-files>
git rebase --continue

# Re-enable the sparse-checkout
git sparse-checkout set <paths-or-patterns>
# Replace `<paths-or-patterns>` with the paths or patterns you had previously used.
```

If anything goes wrong, you can always switch back to your `backup-branch` to start over.