# How to disable sparse checkout after enabled?

Tags: git

I enabled a sparse checkout

```
git init
git remote add <url>
git config --global core.sparseCheckout true
echo "assets" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

Git checked out only the assets folder for me

But now, I want to enable full branch checkout again (checkout folders/files), but it doesn't seem to work.

1) first I disabled config

```
git config --global core.sparseCheckout false
```

2) removed the entries in .git/info/sparse-checkout

But git didn't checkout any of the other folders/files for me, it seems it is sticking to 'assets' folder.

Could anyone tell me how can I reset/disable this sparse checkout without creating a new repo.?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Update with git 2.25+ (Q1 2020), as I mentioned in "[Git sparse checkout with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309)", you now have the [`git sparse-checkout` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout).

More precisely, as noted in [Tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74296/tao)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62798674/6309):

[`git sparse-checkout disable`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt-emdisableem)

> Disable the `core.sparseCheckout` config setting, and restore the working directory to include all files.
> Leaves the sparse-checkout file intact so a later `git sparse-checkout init` command may return the working directory to the same state.

---

Original answer: 2016

You can see an example of "undoing" a sparse checkout [in this script](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/blob/master/sparse_checkout.sh#L40-L51) by Roscoe A. Bartlett:

[`git read-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) is important.

```sh
echo "Undoing sparse checkout"

# Get the full tree back
echo "*" > $SC_FILE
git config core.sparsecheckout true
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD

# Wipe out all traces of sparse checkout support
rm $SC_FILE
git config core.sparsecheckout false
```

---

The article "[Adventures in Git - SparseCheckouts](http://www.richsomerfield.com/post/2014-03-05-adventures-in-git-sparsecheckouts/)" by [Rich Somerfield](http://www.richsomerfield.com//about/) propose a similar option (also valid for submodules):

```sh
echo "/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "/*" > .git/modules/<MODULEPATH>/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree -mu HEAD
git config core.sparseCheckout false
```

---

[braham-snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5054877/braham-snyder) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190800/how-to-disable-sparse-checkout-after-enabled/36195275#comment79984615_36195275) that **updating** a `.git/info/sparse-checkout` (to checkout and track additional files) can be achieved with

```sh
git read-tree --dry-run HEAD
```

Comment: tested, this works fine to me.  
The key is to issue "git read-tree -mu" which I missed.

Comment: FWIW: I arrived here because I merely wanted git to recognize my updates to my existing `.git/info/sparse-checkout` (to checkout and track additional files) -- running only `git read-tree --dry-run HEAD` appeared to achieve that

Comment: @braham-snyder Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 14):

*While VonC's answer is certainly correct and will help with the imminent problem, I feel the need to elaborate and explain the underlying issue.*

### Background

Git's `sparse-checkout` makes use of the [`skip-worktree` bit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit), which basically tells git to consider the file in your working directory to be "up to date", regardless of the true state.

When using `sparse-checkout` git will apply this bit to all files which do not match the patterns described in your `sparse-checkout` file. When disabling `sparse-checkout`, or deleting the pattern file, this bits will still be set and the files won't return. [You can read about it here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout)

As such you have to remove the `skip-worktree` bit manually from the files in question. The easiest approach certainly being the suggestions from VonC.

### But why?

The reasoning behind this is quite simple. The `skip-worktree` bit is not exclusively used for `sparse-checkout` but it's rather a tool in git's toolkit. Other processes make use of the same bit, or a user might even use it own his own (personally I use it regularly to ignore changes to configuration files when debugging).

---

***On a sidenote**: You can actually get a list of the files which have been flagged with the `skip-worktree` bit, by using `git ls-files -v`. This  will list all files under version control; the files with the `skip-worktree` bit are prefixed with a `S`.*

*If you only want to list the `skip-worktree` flagged files you can easily parse and grep the list with the following command: `git ls-files -v | grep '^S' | cut -d' ' -f2`.*

Comment: I didn't see your answer at first. +1. Good mention of the skip-worktree bit.

Answer (score 13):

While it is still experimental as of git 2.27, there is now a command that handles this more transparently/intuitively:

```
git sparse-checkout disable
```

My understanding is that you shouldn't have to set `core.sparseCheckout` manually anymore, it should be enabled, configured and disabled using this new `git sparse-checkout` command.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one

Comment: Agree. This is the way to solve this after 2020.