# convert a sparse checkout clone to a full checkout

Tags: git, version-control, sparse-checkout

I have a fairly huge repo and I completed a sparse checkout using

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout --depth 1 --sparse <repolink>
```

I have sparse added most of the elements and now, I want to make it a full clone.

How can I do this, without having to delete this sparse checkout files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36195275/7976758 `git sparse-checkout disable` https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+disable+sparse-checkout