# clone specific commit bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

_

I have an project in bitbucket and I want to clone specific commit  from it
these are the commits, I want without the last two of them

[image]

butin SourceTree I can't see the commits number `b6981f9` and `1fb876a`
just the last number `da84f64`
[image]

I think because the last 3 pushed together, what I should do?

Comment: Why must it only be a single commit rather than just cloning the whole repository?  If this is actually a requirement you should probably explain why.

Comment: @Chris yes I want the whole repository except the last 2 commits, I don't need it, so how I can specific that cloning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> yes I want the whole repository except the last 2 commits, I don't need it, so how I can specific that cloning?

The normal way is to:

- clone everything
- checkout a new branch (or reset the current branch) to `HEAD~2`

  ```
  git checkout -b newBranch @~2
  ```

Other than that:

- [shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309) allows you to get the last n commits (which is not what you want)
- [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34104193/6309) is about subfolders (not sub-commits)
- [fetch single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309) would not get all commits but some.

> I have partners in project but we got bug in the last 2 commits

So, with SourceTree:

- clone the repo (normal clone)
- select the commit from which you want to work: double-click the commit to check it out, then click 'Branch'.

Once you have created an new branch, work and add new commits, then push your bugfix branch.

Comment: Actually I'm so beginner with git, so I'm little confused, now do you mean I should clone every thing, and then what I should do delete the last 2 commits from the project?

Comment: Also can I do that by sourceTree?

Comment: @joda not delete, but start working from HEAD~2, in order for your new branch HEAD to start from where you want to. Are you the only one working on that repo?

Comment: @joda Always start with command-line: much more precise than any GUI.

Comment: @joda But yes, you can do that from SourceTree as well: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54861/how-can-i-create-a-branch-in-sourcetree-git-from-arbitrary-commit

Comment: Ok, but HEAD~2 means? ist number of commits I don't need it or the name of branch or what? and no I have partners in project but we got bug in the last 2 commits

Comment: @joda `HEAD~2` is a revision selection top reference ancestors: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References:  `HEAD~2` means “the first parent of the first parent,” or “the grandparent” – it traverses the first parents the number of times you specify. .

Comment: I got that thank you so much, but the problem now the last three commits "da84f64 - 1fb876a - b6981f9" was pushed together like my image in the question، so SourceTree just show me the last one "da84f64" but I need the commit "b6981f9" how I can access to it?

Comment: @joda go to your log view of your cloned repo: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/viewing-log-history-of-a-repository-785615840.html. You will see all commits there.

Comment: yes I open it, but I still see the one last commit, it should be the last three like what I see in bitbucket site

Comment: @joda you should see all commits from all branches as shown in https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2016/03/01/sourcetree-design-whats-next/. Otherwise, edit your question with a screenshot illustrating the issue.

Comment: @joda you should still see 1fb and b68 commits below by scrolling done: they have been merged, but are still there in the history.

Comment: scrolling where? unfortunately the history actually the same  branch master

Comment: @joda scrolling *down*: at the right side of your screenshot, there should be a way to scroll down.

Comment: ohh I see it, now I create branch with it, how I clone it?

Comment: @joda it is already cloned: a cloned Git repo includes the full complete history. Symply create a branch from that commit, as mentioned in https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54861/how-can-i-create-a-branch-in-sourcetree-git-from-arbitrary-commit

Comment: The source tree option is handier. Thanks