# Clone Git branches to new repository

Tags: git

I have new structure (new repository and  its own branches) for new version of my project , and i need to clone some parts of last version to keep history of old commits for new programmers.
let say my old repository include whole project with all plugins , and in this version we focus only on plugins and we do not want to clone whole project , but those plugins which we use must have git history to check old commit.
how it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - clone only part of the repository and get pulls only for that part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103146/git-clone-only-part-of-the-repository-and-get-pulls-only-for-that-part)

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the whole repository and then remove the unwanted parts using `git filter-branch`.

This is how you remove a single file from the repository history:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```

where `filename` is the path to the file you want to remove.

Or if the part you want to keep is in a single directory, you can do

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all
```

This rewrites the history as if `foodir/` had been its project root and discards all other history.

Read [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) carefully to apply it for your specific case.