# Git commit/Push/Pull with sparse checkout

Tags: git, version-control, sparse-checkout

I started Git yesterday and before that I was using SVN since many years. Let me explain you what exactly I am trying to achieve:

I have a main git repo for different projects. Something like this:

- main_repo/proj1
- main_repo/proj2
- main_repo/proj3

I can't create separate repos for these sub-projects. Now I (or other users) should be able to checkout/commit/push/pull in these independent projects.

For this thing I am trying sparse-checkout with following commands:

1. `mkdir proj1; cd proj1`
2. `git init`
3. `git remote add origin https://main_repo`
4. `git config core.sparsecheckout true`
5. `echo "proj1/" > .git/info/sparse-checkout`
6. `git pull origin master`

Now what I need is to get all the files present in proj1 in the same current dir. What I am getting is something like this:

```
/proj1/proj1/files_and_dirs_in_proj1
```

What I need:

```
/proj1/files_and_dirs_in_proj1
```

Second this is that the checkout-dir doesn't behaves like a git repo. It doesn't carry any .git dir. So I don't understand how to do commits/push/pull in sparse-checkedout projs.

I hope I explained it well. Please suggest.

Comment: One repository for multiple independent projects sounds like a design mistake. Care to elaborate why you can't split them up?

Comment: @wonce he didn't say they were independent. Given that they are probably not independent, there are many advantages: https://medium.com/@maoberlehner/monorepos-in-the-wild-33c6eb246cb9

Comment: @user2793078 : I believe a symlink is all you need. In statement 1, use a different name e.g. `allprojects` . Then add #7 : `cd .. && ln -s allprojects/proj1 proj1`

Answer (score 2):

If I have correctly understood you then you want to:

- create git repository with 3 projects inside it (subfolders proj1, proj2, proj3)
- create separate directories for each team working with its project (e.g. teamproj1, teamproj2, teamproj3)
- these folders should have only files belonging to appropriate project (e.g. teamproj1 folder have only proj1 subfolder, etc)

In this case you can use this simple steps:

1) Add your main repo to git

```
git init
git remote add origin ...
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push
```

2) Clone & adjust your git repos for each commands (teamproj1, teamproj2, teamproj3, ...). Repeat code below for each team/project

```
git clone ... teamproj1
cd teamproj1
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo 'proj1' › .git/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree -m -u HEAD
```

3) Bingo. Each command will be with its own folder and project. This folder is normal git repo, but this repo will show only some files which will be in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`

I've added some drawings to facilitate understanding of this scheme

[image]

Comment: first of all thanks for your effort... Now my quest, if I do git clone ... teamproj1, it will clone the whole main repo... which is huge and that what I really dont want.

Comment: this is the problem for sparse checkout in git `Unfortunately it does not affect the size of the overall local repository but can be helpful if you have a huge tree of folders`. You checkout all repo, but git shows you only subset if you enabled `core.sparsecheckout` feature.
See: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/

Comment: thats unbelievable. So it means there is nothing really like a sub dir check-out like svn. What you mentioned sounds like 'checkout everything and then  hide the unwanted stuff'

Comment: It's not appropriate using of git. Why you need to use one repository for all projects? Maybe you can  put each project to separate repo?

Answer (score 1):

The recent [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309) can help, especially when combined with [`git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt)

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
git config core.sparseCheckoutCone false
git sparse-checkout disable

# Add the expected pattern, to include just a subfolder without top files:
git sparse-checkout set /mySubFolder/

# populate working-tree with only the right files:
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

Plus, with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), "[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe069dce6251f40eb3d54861500c92afb0e481d9/Documentation/git-add.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> and [`git rm`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe069dce6251f40eb3d54861500c92afb0e481d9/Documentation/git-rm.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm))</sup> learned not to touch those paths that are outside of sparse checkout.

So you won't make any mistake with paths outside of the relevant submodules.

See [commit d5f4b82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5f4b8260f623d6fdef36d5eaa8a0c2350390472), [commit a20f704](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a20f70478ffcc66d30936920ebcc35ebfc12a7c7), [commit b243012](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b243012cb39e2151ffae96bded2387751d876d12), [commit 719630e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/719630eb4826ff7f36bc060533dbccc3c96d151c), [commit d73dbaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d73dbafc2c25eb45090d6aa9d56fc21b40c78083), [commit 6594afc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6594afc3cc4bd87247b44d3d3bf75d693fc066aa), [commit 4e95698](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e9569834936a8c0df8c9afdc0334f1b96b20914) (08 Apr 2021) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe069dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe069dce6251f40eb3d54861500c92afb0e481d9), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rm`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5f4b8260f623d6fdef36d5eaa8a0c2350390472): honor sparse checkout patterns
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> [`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d5f4b8260f623d6fdef36d5eaa8a0c2350390472/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> refrains from adding or updating index entries that are outside the current sparse checkout, but [`git rm`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d5f4b8260f623d6fdef36d5eaa8a0c2350390472/Documentation/git-rm.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm))</sup> doesn't follow the same restriction.
> This is somewhat counter-intuitive and inconsistent.
> So make `rm` honor the sparsity rules and advise on how to remove `SKIP_WORKTREE` entries just like `add` does.
> Also add some tests for the new behavior.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d5f4b8260f623d6fdef36d5eaa8a0c2350390472/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L123-L125):

> Advice shown when either [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) or [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)
> is asked to update index entries outside the current sparse
> checkout.

`git rm` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d5f4b8260f623d6fdef36d5eaa8a0c2350390472/Documentation/git-rm.txt#L26-L28):

> allowing the file to be removed from just the index. When
> sparse-checkouts are in use (see [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)),
> `git rm` will only remove paths within the sparse-checkout patterns.

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2f713668784266b4682816fadcf2034d846e9cc1/Documentation/git-add.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> can work better with the sparse index.

See [commit 42f8ed6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42f8ed6ca24854141c34aa82472ca126fdaeaf65), [commit 939fa07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/939fa07582a2c9455e71f599263e2dcbe1d655b5), [commit 4eaffd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4eaffd81a5fbffc692f1044374a3a16689fc37a5), [commit 5e7cbab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e7cbab19680745d4f3e0c50903025d9f02e7468), [commit 83ad8ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83ad8ca596dd879d2907a240fb24a1603bb1decc) (29 Jul 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2f71366](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f713668784266b4682816fadcf2034d846e9cc1), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/939fa07582a2c9455e71f599263e2dcbe1d655b5): ignore outside the sparse-checkout in refresh()
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Since [b243012](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b243012cb39e2151ffae96bded2387751d876d12) (`refresh_index()`: add flag to ignore `SKIP_WORKTREE` entries, 2021-04-08, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe069dce6251f40eb3d54861500c92afb0e481d9) listed in [batch #14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d677e5b1537692a4f875740a6e9853c24285f02)) `(refresh_index()`: add flag to ignore `SKIP_WORKTREE` entries, 2021-04-08), '[`git add --refresh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/939fa07582a2c9455e71f599263e2dcbe1d655b5/Documentation/git-add.txt#L155)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---refresh))</sup> `<path>` will output a warning message when the path is outside the sparse-checkout definition.
> The implementation of this warning happened in parallel with the sparse-index work to add `ensure_full_index()` calls throughout the codebase.
>
> Update this loop to have the proper logic that checks to see if the pathspec is outside the sparse-checkout definition.
> This avoids the need to expand the sparse directory entry and determine if the path is tracked, untracked, or ignored.
> We simply avoid updating the stat() information because there isn't even an entry that matches the path!

Answer (score -2):

First off, git is not svn, different concepts, different approaches.  Git is a full source-control system on the client, not a front-end to a remote server

And one of the differences is you clone the whole repository and not subsections.  I believe there are ways to make it *appear* that you've only cloned a subset but in reality the whole repo is there.

In the testing/usage I've done, it doesn't matter.  Yes, perhaps the initial cloning is a little slower but after that it's really fast.  My company has a large 4G+ source tree repository, 100s of developers, everyone has a complete copy of the repo even though their responsibility might be segmented, even remote over our mediocre corporate WAN there have been no problems.