# Sparse checkout and shallow clone

Tags: git, github, repository, sparse-checkout, shallow-clone

When I tried to add library to CDN it's says I need to **sparse checkout and shallow clone** to make PR easily. So what's those? I read some articles but didn't understand well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cndjs doc](https://github.com/simple-statistics/cdnjs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#a-sparse-checkout-and-shallow-clone) points to [`documents/sparseCheckout.md`](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/documents/sparseCheckout.md)

It involves:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
# edit .git/info/sparse-checkout
# and 
git pull origin master --depth 10
```

That allows you to limit the data you need to work on that huge repo:

> Currently, cdnjs's repo is too huge and some people have issues with using it when it is this big.
>   To get around the issue or repo size you can use sparse-checkout. It lets you check out only the files you want, so that the whole directory in your computer won't need to be 11GB, but only about 1GB (you can make this even smaller with shallow pull too!)

---

Update January 2020, 4 years later:

You would need to use the [Git 2.25 `git sparse-checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309) command.

Comment: Thanks, from the doc I happened to be in the page https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/sparseCheckout.md which gave me nothing. Can you give more details on `sparse checkout` and `shallow pull`? so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @AsimKT https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/documents/sparseCheckout.md has all the details