# Git gives invalid path issue while switching between branches

Tags: git, github

i have cloned the project in my windows machine(windows 10) and try to switch to different branch. but getting invalid path issue[1]

```
#git switch develop
```

[1]

```
error: invalid path 'src/main/resources/examples/invoice-item-create-request-eip.json '
error: invalid path 'src/main/resources/examples/invoice-item-create-request-orcl.json '
```

Why is that? I didn't get any issue /warning when i clone the project

Comment: `git switch` is kind if new.... what happens if you try the old `git checkout`instead?

Comment: # git checkout develop also gives same issue

Comment: Note that these paths end with a space—the file's name is `path/to/file<SPACE>` and not just `path/to/file`, where I used <SPACE> to emphasize the blank—and your version of Git demands that no file's name can end with a space like that. Those are the names of files in the commit identified by the name `develop`; presumably, the commit identified by your current branch name does not contain files with these funny ended-by-a-blank names.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't get any issue /warning when i clone the project

Probably because the default checked out `master` branch did not include files with a trailing space in it.

See if you can [**rename** those files directly on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/renaming-a-file) in the develop branch (through their web GUI interface), and then clone the repository again (and switch to `develop`)

If you cannot rename them, exclude them through a [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) (new command, still experimental with Git 2.25: [I present it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309)).

---

As noted by [wdtj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442731/wdtj) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049660/git-gives-invalid-path-issue-while-switching-between-branches/60051207?noredirect=1#comment112718446_60051207):

> if you are using `sparse-checkout` on Windows, you may need to add [`git config core.protectNTFS false`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreprotectNTFS) per [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2777](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2777)

Comment: you are right master branch doesn't have those files. Only in develop branch those files are there. but, i cannot rename the files(out of my control). How can i overcome that issue in windows to switch between branches?

Comment: @Ratha THrough a sparse checkout, in order to exclude those files: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

Comment: Note that if you are using sparse-checkout on windows, you may need to add core.protectNTFS false per https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2777

Comment: @wdtj Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with additional links.