# git sparse-checkout ignore specific file type

Tags: linux, git, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

I have a git repository with a bunch of large csv in them, which I don't want to clone, so I came across git sparse-checkout and this post: https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/

From this post I took following:

```
git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/john_doe/repo-with-big-csv.git
cd repo-with-big-csv
git sparse-checkout init --cone
```

Then I edit the `.git/info/sparse-checkout` and add the following (adapted from [example](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/#cone-mode-restricted-patterns-improve-performance) in page above):

```
/*
!**/*.csv
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly. After `git pull` some folders are cloned, some are not. I also noticed a warning, when I do `git sparse-checkout list` I get:

```
warning: unrecognized pattern: '**/*.csv'
warning: disabling cone pattern matching
/*
!**/*.csv
```

What's the proper way to ignore a certain file type only?

Comment: `**` doesn't seem to fit the model of the optimized cone-mode bloom-filter path filtering. I think the example on that web page is just poorly described. (You don't have to use cone mode, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

See "[Git sparse checkout with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309)" and make sure to use Git 2.26.x, which has some fixes for the [`git sparse-checkout` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout).

> When in cone mode, the git sparse-checkout set subcommand takes a list of directories instead of a list of sparse-checkout patterns
>
> If `core.sparseCheckoutCone=true`, then Git will parse the sparse-checkout file expecting patterns of these types. Git will warn if the patterns do not match.

You need to only use restrict patterns based on folder prefix matches.

---

The [OP Frode Akselsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3736779/frode-akselsen) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623691/git-sparse-checkout-ignore-specific-file-type/61628291#comment109021337_61628291):

> **my example is actually working**: the folders that don't show up just contain *only* `.csv` files, hence, after applying the rules in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`, nothing is in the folder anymore and therefore Git doesn't show the folder.

I confirm Git will only show content: if  folder has no file (no "content"), said folder is not visible.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that my example is actually working, the folders that don't show up just contain only .csv files, hence, after applying the rules in `.git/info/sparse-checkout` nothing is in the folder anymore and therefore git doesn't show the folder.

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen Thank you for this informative feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @rkudinov I am sorry to hear that. What is missing in your specific case, in order to solve your issue?