# How do I ignore a conftest.py file at the root of a git submodule (e.g. submodule/conftest.py) when running pytest on the parent project?

Tags: python, git, pytest, git-submodules, python-3.8

### Question

How can I tell pytest to ignore **all test files including conftest.py** within a repository's git submodule as these tests and files are irrelevant to the parent repository's test suite?

### Background

I have a number of git submodules in my project which house their own self contained testing configurations.

When I try to use pytest in the "parent" repository, I am getting this error because pytest is collecting the conftest.py files within my submodules.

```
>pytest
=================================================== ERRORS =================================================== 
_______________________________________ ERROR collecting test session ________________________________________ 
Defining 'pytest_plugins' in a non-top-level conftest is no longer supported:
It affects the entire test suite instead of just below the conftest as expected.
  C:\Users\user\git\project\submodule\conftest.py
Please move it to a top level conftest file at the rootdir:
  C:\Users\user\git\project
For more information, visit:
  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-plugins-in-non-top-level-conftest-files
========================================== short test summary info =========================================== ERROR
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ============================================== 1 error in 0.45s ==============================================
```

My "parent" git repository structure looks like:

```
./.git
./project1/__main__.py
./project1/__init__.py
./project1/other_stuff/
./test/
./conftest.py
./setup.cfg
./submodule/.git
./submodule/project2/__main__.py
./submodule/project2/__init__.py
./submodule/project2/other_stuff/
./submodule/conftest.py
./submodule/setup.cfg
./submodule/test/
```

One (cumbersome) option may be to only run pytest with uninitialized submodules. However, if I do not initialize the git submodules then I cannot run integration tests with those libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by creating a `pytest.ini` file at the root of my project specifying the test path explicitly:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
testpaths =
    tests
```

This way the submodule path gets ignored. Messing with which files get checked out of the submodule sounds like a pain tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You could [setup your submodule with a sparse-checkout rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233492/6309) (with an [exclusion rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61623691/6309)) in order to not load their own `conftest.py`

If that file is not there in the submodule, it would be "ignored" automatically by `pytest`.

For example, run:

```
> cd ./submodule
> git sparse-checkout init
> git sparse-checkout set /* !conftest.py
> git sparse-checkout list
/*
!conftest.py
```

Comment: This sounds like a good approach but I am new to the idea of a git sparse-checkout. I've started digging through those other links and reading the git-sparse-checkout documentation. Are you saying I should put sparse checkout in a branch, say `submodule-release`, of the _submodule_ repository and then have the parent repository refer to that branch?

Comment: @FrancisSziebert I don't think a sparse checkout directive is stored in the repository (to be included in a future clone). It is declared in the local repository configuration, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233492/6309

Comment: After a little more reading, that makes sense. My edit example works for my local development. For a little sanity check, If I was running pytest on the parent as part of a pipeline, would I just include these sparse-checkout commands in my makefile prior to testing?

Comment: @FrancisSziebert Thank you for the edit. Approved.

Comment: @FrancisSziebert Yes, the idea would be to integrate those commands to your pipeline.