# Export files between two last tag git

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, git

My ASP.NET MVC web app is written using C# and uses SQL Server stored procedures.

I am using Git for code source control, and each time I deploy, I will create a tag to define the version deployed.

Example: `tag1_2021_07_29_11_00`, `tag2_2021_07_30_09_01`... and the tag will be time I deploy, this time deploy can random.

And the stored procedure I need to run  is list file between two tag:
`tag2_2021_07_30_09_01` and `tag1_2021_07_29_11_00`.

(Example `sp1.sql`, `sp2.sql`, `sp3.sql` I will run it in SQL Server Management Studio)

I want to automate the deployment with cmd for saving time.

I created successfully cmd command to build and export deployment web source code, but i don't know the command to export my `.sql` file between `tag1` and `tag2` into one folder.

Do note that I see that TortoiseGit has a function "`export this version..`" when I show `git log` and choose my list SQL stored procedure file `sp1.sql`,`sp2.sql`...

Could anyone help me to achieve my goal using cmd to export list store?

---

This is my cmd build command, I need and some cmd line to export list SQL to compress with my source (into `deploy_PROD_%datetime%.7z`):

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd__HH.mm"') do set datetime=%%a

del /s /q  "D:\botdeploy\*"
cd /D D:\Source & git checkout PROD & git pull & git tag PROD_deploy_%datetime% & git push --tags
cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Msbuild" D:\Source\CRM.csproj  /t:Restore,Rebuild /p:outdir="D:\botdeploy\\" /p:Configuration=Release & del  /q "D:\botdeploy\_PublishedWebsites\CRM\Web.config" & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -t7z C:\Users\Nam\Desktop\deploy_PROD_%datetime%.7z D:\botdeploy\_PublishedWebsites\CRM\*
pause
```

Comment: Could you share what you already have? This might help...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to list files added/modified (but not removed) between two tags, see, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65820201/6309)

```
git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter=AM tag1 tag2 > list
```

Once you have a list of files, you could use it in a dedicated cloned repository where you [can sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309) only the files you want (with [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)):

```sh
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout --branch tag2 /url/remote/repo
cd repo
git sparse-checkout init 
# for each file in list
git sparse-checkout add <aFile>
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

Finally, you can [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) that repository, in order to get an archive with only the files you want, at the right version (`tag2`, the most recent one)

Comment: @LeGEC It does not indeed. Removed.