# How can I use "gocode" to autocomplete code and use "gopls" ust for code navigation when I use Vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

My company's project has so mush code.The autocomplete provided by "`gopls`" has a delay for about 1 second.
That was a little upset for me.

Then I find that gocode's autocomplete is faster.

But when I turn on "gopls", "gocode" won't work.
And if I turn off "gopls", I can't have the navigation provided by the "gopls".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the

- [`nfs/gocode` README](https://github.com/nsf/gocode):

> VERY IMPORTANT: this project is not maintained anymore, look for alternatives or forks if you need Go autocompletion tool

- [`mdempsky/gocode` README](https://github.com/mdempsky/gocode)

> For a better autocompletion experience with Go, we suggest you use the Go language server, [gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/README.md).

So do check first if *all* the company code is actually needed to compile your project.
Maybe you could do some [sparse-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309) in order to not get all the code, but only the part you need.
And make sure your modules are all needed, using [`go mod tidy`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy).

Comment: @LGZ Was it enough for you to solve your issue?