# Downloading the certain folder from GitHub with token method

Tags: github, token

I want to download specific folder from GitHub, and not the whole package.
But this one folder is also huge, that's why someone recommended me a token method, but I actually don't know what is it and how it works, and I also did not found the helpful information about this method in Internet.

So maybe someone can explain me, how can I download this folder with the token-method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the token can be the [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), in order to authenticate you, avoiding any anonymous access, and allowing a greater number of queries.

Second, "[Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194523/6309)" refers to one of the most active tools: [**`refined-github/refined-github`**](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github).

That Chrome extension will add a download button on all folders:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1402241/35044451-fd3e2326-fbc2-11e7-82e1-61ec7bee612b.png]

And you will enter your token in the [options of this extension](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github/blob/cd201c1c80a2a4c25d3eeb511948d2ca84a42855/distribution/options.html#L15-L19).

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you for your answer. Actually I tried also this method, but unfortunately it doesn't help me. The folder wasn't downloaded. I suggest the dataset is too huge for this extension. Do you know maybe another program or method which could help me?

Comment: @Kathi With a recent 2.34 Git, you have: https://github.blog/2021-11-10-make-your-monorepo-feel-small-with-gits-sparse-index/ That could help cloning just the part you need from this giant repository. Example at the beginning of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309

Comment: I tried to execute this terminal command, but get too many arguments from the terminal. My goal is to download the tweets from this repository from January and I tried this command:git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/lopezbec/COVID19_Tweets_Dataset/tree/main/Summary_Details/2021_01cd git                                                                                              I am just a beginner, and maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: @Kathi When you clone, you clone a repository as a all, not a tree/subfolder: `git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/lopezbec/COVID19_Tweets_Dataset`