# Git - Illegal characters in path git visual studio 2019

Tags: ios, git, xamarin.forms, bitbucket

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms project and I'm in the master branch and I'm trying to check out another branch but I'm getting this error in VS 2019:

[image]

& I'm getting this error when using commands:
[image]

Notes:

- This is my first time checking out this branch
- I can check out other branches normally
- The paths mentioned in the error don't exist.
- I don't care about the ios application for this project, I focus on the Android one.

What should I do to fix this error and check out the branch successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In command line, try and set a [sparse checkout clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321565/6309) first, then open the IDE for your Xamarin project:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/remote/project
cd project
git sparse-checkout set /* !/.vs/JM?/xs/project-cache
git sparse-checkout init
# that sets git config core.sparseCheckoutCone true
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

The idea is to ignore the content of `.vs/JM?/xs/project-cache` (assuming `.vs` is right under the root folder of the repository) on checkout (of any branch).