# Perform git sparse-checkout of everything except a list of subdirectories

Tags: git

I have the following (mono)repo structure

```
└── dir1
    ├── subdir1
    │   ├── subdir1a
    │   ├── subdir1b
    │   └── subdir1c
    └── subdir2
        ├── subdir2a
        ├── subdir2b
        ├── subdir2c

└── dir2
└── dir3
```

I want to checkout everything **except** (say) `subdir1b` and `subdir1c`.

Is there a way to perform a sparse checkout of **everything** except perhaps some subdirs?

Asking because perhaps (if there is such a work around) it is easier to state to `git` what you do **not** want to be checkout rather than start listing everything that is to be checkout.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#_full_pattern_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [Git 2.25+ `git sparse-checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309), I just tested:

```sh
C:\Users\vonc\git>git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/git/git git2
Cloning into 'git2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 200317, done.
remote: Total 200317 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 200317
Receiving objects: 100% (200317/200317), 74.10 MiB | 26.40 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (127965/127965), done.

C:\Users\vonc\git>cd git2

C:\Users\vonc\git\git2>git sparse-checkout init

C:\Users\vonc\git\git2>git read-tree -mu HEAD
remote: Enumerating objects: 459, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (392/392), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (392/392), done.
remote: Total 459 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 67
Receiving objects: 100% (459/459), 1.88 MiB | 9.14 MiB/s, done.
```

The result is a repository with no subfolders.

Lets start to add all subfolders, except `Documentation\technical`

```sh
# edit .git\info\sparse-checkout
/*
!/Documentation/technical/
# ... Add your other excluded folders

C:\Users\vonc\git\git2>git sparse-checkout reapply
```

The end result is the all [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git/) repository, *without* `Documentation/technical/`