# git download a file from a private repo

Tags: git, download, token, private, archive

I want to download a file from a private repo. I want to do this with "git" (not gitlab/github api).

Git provide this way https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive. You can fetch a file [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18331440/13663683)

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md
```

However I cannot use ssh. I want to download file using http and a token I have.

I can clone my repo like this:

```
git clone -b branch http://oauth2:$gitToken@${gitRepo}
```

but if u make a command like this:

```
git archive --remote=http://oauth2:$gitToken@${gitRepo} branch filename
```

You encounter an error:

```
fatal: operation not supported by protocol
```

**So the question is how we can download a file from a private git repo using a token.**
(git-archive approach or other (git) way)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git archive fatal: Operation not supported by protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258599/git-archive-fatal-operation-not-supported-by-protocol)

Comment: Ty for comment. I'm afraid it does not. I'm using git v2.25.1, that is rather new version. Also I want to use token in request because it is a private repo.

Comment: Git doesn't really download *files*, but rather downloads *commits*. See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71921698/1256452) for ways to make Git download fewer commits than usual. When you use `git archive` you're not invoking Git as usual, which is why you have to use the ssh method to do this with GitHub. Other sites may have their own special rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping there was a straightforward solution to this. But the only way I could achieve downloading files was "sparse-checkout" as [they said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71921698/13663683).

However I modified the way to get only a file, not a directory so it differ from that instruction.

For downloading file u can do this:

```
git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --no-checkout -b branchName http://oauth2:$gitToken@$gitRepo repoFolder
cd repoFolder
git sparse-checkout set $fileName
```

Those git clone flags are for minimizing getting extra files.

And this will fetch your file in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub (and I suspect most public Git hosting service provider) does not support remote archiving through HTTPS.

The more modern git way would be the recent `git clone --filter`/`sparse-checkout` approach

```sh
git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse https://[token]@github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git
cd COVID-19/
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout add /the folder you want/
```

See also [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366001/6309), where I edit `.git\info\sparse-checkout`

Comment: Ty for Answering. In sparse-checkout u can get a specific directory. Its not for getting a specific file. Am I right?
And for limitation in public Git hosts u mentioned, can it be solved in personal git host? Then how u can add token to request?

Comment: @mnr Yes to the first: that would limit the number of files to one folder. I am not sure regarding the second question: I suppose that indeed you can add support for remote archive on a Git server you control, but I do not know (yet) how.

Comment: Thank u for helping

Comment: @mnr Don't forget to accept an answer for this or your past question. You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, starting tomorrow).

Answer (score 2):

I have modified previous answer and have got working script for downloading only one file with read access token

```bash
 git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none \
  -b master https://<my_token_name>:<my_token>@<my_git_repo>.git tmp_dir && \
  cd tmp_dir && \
  git sparse-checkout set <path_to_file_in_repo> && \
  git checkout master && \
  test -f <path_to_file_in_repo>
```