# Git can not clone a repository in window env, because some special file names

Tags: git, window

I am trying to do a git clone from a repository in my window, but the source code contains these 2 files, that my git cloning on window keeps failing.

```
./templates/extender/sync/os_firmware/[4.2.2.291,4.2.3.517)|[7.0.0.0,7.0.1.0).jinja2
./templates/extender/sync/os_firmware/(-inf,4.2.2.291)|[4.2.3.517,7.0.0.0)|[7.0.1.0,+inf).jinja2
```

To work around, I have to create a special branch on ubuntu, get rid of these 2 files, and then have this special branch cloned on my window, ... once my code is committed, I had to have these 2 files added back.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a [sparse-checkout with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321565/6309) after a `git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/your/repository`

The [documentation mentions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#_internalsfull_pattern_set):

> For example, to select everything, and then to remove the file
> unwanted (so that every file will appear in your working tree except
> the file named unwanted):
>
> ```
> git sparse-checkout set --no-cone '/*' '!unwanted'
> ```
>
> These patterns are just placed into the `$GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout`
> as-is, so the contents of that file at this point would be
>
> ```
> /*
> !unwanted
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. For those who have the same issue as mine, "git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/your/repository" would clone an empty repository => "git sparse-checkout set your/desired/check_out/dir ", will checkout the needed parts only.