# Allow other dev to use my repository as a remote

Tags: git, github

I have some code I want to share with another developer. We plan to eventually push it publicly, but don't want to have anything public at the moment.

I have a public GitHub account, and I created a repository for some code.
That has been pushed to origin (GitHub), and is public.

I have created a branch locally, but have not pushed it to origin yet, as I want to keep it private for now.

Is there any way that we can setup another developer to use my local branch as a remote, without having to push it to origin first?

Can he add a `git remote`? And if so, what would he need for the URL for it?

Apologies if I'm getting the terminology wrong, I'm fairly new to Git.
I'm using GitExtensions, mixed in with some GitBash, and have my repository hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in "[Having a private branch of a public repo on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983450/6309)", your repo, if public, give read-access to *all* its content.

That includes all branches.

But you can add to your local repo as many remote as you want, so you can add the url of a private repo (either one created on GitHub, with a paid account, or BitBucket).
See "[Manage remote repositories](http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote_feature.html#manage-remote-repositories)"

[image: http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/manage_remote_repositories.png]

That way, you can push your private branch to that new remote.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I can't currently do it on a free GitHub account. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby indeed: private GitHub repo means paid account on GitHub.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into the alternate options. Thanks.