# GITHUB allow someone to view my private repository

Tags: github

I would like to allow someone to view the work I've done in my private repository. How should I do this?

I looked at https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-private-repository-public; however, the settings tab doesnt show up.

It does, however, when viewing my fork. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

Public/Private can be set in the settings of a repository. You'll find the option in the "Danger Zone". If you are not the owner of the repository the option will be greyed out.

If you don't want to make the repository public you could add a collaborator.

You can't edit the settings of repositories that don't belong to you. A fork is your copy of another repository. If you want to contribute back to the original I would suggest using the pull request feature.

Comment: It doesnt show up for some reason. Only in my fork can I see the settings.

Comment: I think what you want is [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request)

Comment: No, I want to allow a person to view the application I wrote

Comment: You can't give someone access to the code if you don't have permission. Maybe you can try [adding a collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository), this will keep the repository private while allowing access by a specific person. Or you could try [duplicating](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository) the repository, then you will have all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

See [Having a private branch of a public repo on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983204/having-a-private-branch-of-a-public-repo-on-github) for the inverse of what you're asking for. Basically GitHub public/private permissions only apply to repositories, and are not granular to individual branches.