# Bitbucket/Github hide git branch from users

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I would like to hide the branch if user has not permission to work on it. Is it possible to do using bitbucket or github?

I know that we do can prevent user to commit changes to a specific branch, but in my case I would like to prevent user even to see the branch and the commits that had been made to it.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having a private branch of a public repo on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983204/having-a-private-branch-of-a-public-repo-on-github)