# git repo to follow just a directory in remote repo

Tags: git

I want to open up a git repo to translate user documentations which belong to a project that hosted on github. Couple of people will also contribute to it via pull requests. I want my repository to contain only user documentation directory and also, track that directory on the origin. This way, I am hoping to keep up with the changes to documentation in mainstream, thus keeping the translation up to date. I am not sure if this is even possible, but I would like to learn how if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git can generally only work on the complete repository, so unless your documentation directory is a submodule (and therefore basically a complete git repository linked into the main repo) that's not possible. You should be able to use gits sparse checkout [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0) to checkout only a part of the repo, but you will still have a copy of the whole repo locally.

Answer (score 0):

It is not, unless it's a submodule, in which case it's not directory, but rather a repository integrated in the project.