# Can I ignore directories from within submodule before submodule update?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in my project that contains lots of media files in the docs/ and demo/ directory. When I 'git submodule update --init' the entire repo is downloaded, and then I can add an ignore file.

Is it possible to ignore these directories before I update/init submodule?

Comment: If they're under version control in the submodule I think the answer is "no", but I'm not 100% confident. I assume removing them from the submodule is out of the question?

Comment: I was thinking that, but then I still have to download them every time I reinitialize the repo. The project is used among many members, and seems a waste to download unneeded docs/demo every time.

Comment: I mean removing or ignoring them upstream in the submodule's repo, but I assume that's not possible since users who use only the submodule would want access to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do appeared in Git 1.7.0 and is called a "sparse checkout". You can find nice examples in the following Stack Overflow threads:

- [Sparse checkout in Git 1.7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0)
- [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

It should work for submodules too as they are nothing more than normal repositories but as you can see in the pointed threads, that functionality still needs some improvements.