# What are the advantages of git submodule over a symbolic link?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository (A) that includes a library code that I need to reuse in the second repository (B).

My understanding is that git submodule does not allow to import only specific path within a repository, the whole repository needs to be imported. Is this correct?

Because of this, I see two solutions to my problem:

1. Have A and B as separate repositories and add a symbolic link from B to a library directory in A.
2. Add a new git repository C with the library and import it as a submodule in A and B.

What are the advantages of the second approach? It seems to me that adding a separate repository for a small library is an overkill that can add unnecessary burden to the project maintenance. Is there any better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main idea is **build reproducibility**: the ability to recover the *exact* configuration (ie the exact list of labels or SHA1) part of what you used at a specific time to build.

In that context (ability to reproduce the build), submodule (and the solution 2) is preferable to any symlink (which is a shortcut to a directory content, without referring to a specific version).

The other alternative is to externalize the lib, *outside* of a *source* control system, into an artifact repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), and leave in your project(s) only a *reference* to the right version of that library to fetch.

Comment: Site question: Do you know if there is any fundamental reason that makes it impossible for a submodule to import only a select directory from a repository? Or is this just a limitation of the current implementation?

Comment: @JanWrobel a submodule is a git repo in itself, and sparse checkout (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0) isn't supported for submodules. The best practice remains for a git repo to represent one "unit of code", not a collection.