# Getting around Git's directory limitations?

Tags: linux, git, centos

I used Subversion for many years. It allowed you to do something very cool:

```
svn checkout http://bla.bla/some/relative/path
```

With git, you can only:

```
svn checkout http://bla.bla <-- I.e. you can't checkout sub directories
```

How do people get around this? My problem is specifically with deployment scripts. I have this directory structure:

```
/db
/www
etc
etc etc
```

So, I need to check out "www" to /home/mysite/public_html. But to do this, I would have to have the exact same structure (i.e. change www to public_html) AND I would have the added problem of it checking out db and all the other files to my home folder.

I do NOT want to have to check it out to a random folder and then have to copy it across, or rsynch it, or do any other stupid unnecessary steps.

So, how do others get around this?

*UPDATE*

It is extremely important that after the code is deployed, that I can simply go onto the server and type "git pull" from within the www directory, to get all the latest files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you can limit a Git repo to a coherent set of file (meaning in your www in one repo, db in another)

Second, if you *have* to keep everything in one repo, you can see if a **[sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0/2340860#2340860)** can help.

Comment: Two repos is a bit overkill just to have this feature. I assume you refer to this: http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/ when you say sparse checkout?

Comment: @coderama this is not a "feature". This is a direct consequence of the decentralized nature of this tool (git): you clone the full history of one repo. It is important to keep that repo content tight, and not treat a repo as a giant base where you can throw everything. You can group repos in a main repo as submodules if you need to keep track of them together.