# How to create a new git repository with a file that is already in a git repository, keeping the commits

Tags: git, file

I have a repository `foo` that contains a file `Alice.js`.

I want to take that file (that has lots of commits) and create a new repository only with the commits from that file.

How can I do this?

---

Example:

#### Initial repository

```
.
+- Alice.js
+- Bob.png
+- Another.file
```

### `do magic`

#### New repository

```
.
+- Alice.js
```

The new repository contains only the commits from `Alice.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `sparse checkout`. The steps would be:

Create a empty repo with remote, as follows:

```
git init <repo>
git remote add -f origin <url>
```

Then, `git config core.sparsecheckout true`. Add files to checkout to `.git/info/sparse-checkout`.

And finally you can pull in the changes: `git pull origin master`.

Comment: And how can bring the `Alice.js` file in the new repository?

Comment: working on it, will update the post you need .git to be updated

Comment: I don't get it: *Add files to checkout to `...`*. What do you mean?

Comment: provide the file paths there like `echo "dir1/dir2/Alice.js" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout`

Comment: It doesn't work: I created the file `.git/info/sparse-checkout` and put there the path to the file: `../../source-repo/Alice.js`.

Comment: Not the relative path on your system, path from the repo main.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67672/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-nash-ag).

Comment: @IonicăBizău try `--depth` flag and also this post might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0

Comment: `--depth` doesn't help us because the commits are not consecutive.