# git svn clone [with Single File]

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I know I can use git-svn to clone a directory into a new Git Repo, but how can I use git-svn to clone a ***single file*** into a new Git repo?

I have a requirement to split up my SVN repository into several GIT repos and I need to clone certain directories into new Git Repositories.  Using git-svn I am able to use the following command for directories:

```
git svn clone "svnRepo/folderName/" "C:/newGitRepo/FolderName"
```

but when I try:

```
git svn clone "svnRepo/folderName/style.css" "C:/newGitRepo/FolderName"
```

it does not work, it gives me the following output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/newGitRepo/FolderName/.git/
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '...trunk/folderName/style.css' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Invalid filesystem path syntax: Cannot replace a directory from within at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 308.
```

Is there anyway to clone a single file into a new Git Repo?

(I am using this version of GIT: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.3.windows.1/Git-2.8.3-32-bit.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot do this exactly as you want to, but there are some way to do it slightly differently :

If what you want to do is a migration from svn to git, what I recommend is that you break down you repositories **within svn**, then you will be able to use git svn clone on each folder. **But** you would lose the ability to commit back to the svn repo from your new git repo (using *git svn dcommit*).

Another solution is to do a **sparse checkout** : [doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout), see also some details in [Sparse checkout in Git 1.7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0)
. **But** you would still have to put the whole content of your directory in the newly created git repository, even it you don't see it on the working directory.

Comment: an example of a solution would be nice