# Setting up a git repository on a server

Tags: git, github

I had posted this question on superuser but didn't get a helpful response. Thought I'd try here since the question does deal with some configurations and settings for using github.

I have a central server with SSO installed. All my machines are connected through the lan to this server. I have also setup a remote git repository on this server. Now what I'd like to do is make the server act as a central repository. All my employees can commit their code to the server and the server pushes it to the remote git repository.

Can someone please help me out with this process? I am new to git and still learning how to use it effectively. So a step-by-step process or an existing document which I can refer to for this?

Also can I integrate it with SSO in any way?

The server itself is setup on a Mac and SSO uses Atlassian Crowd.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what SSO is, but it seems like this question has been asked before. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589082/using-git-as-a-centralized-version-server

Comment: SSO is Single-Sign On. The other question is for one person making all the changes. I am talking about a team making the changes. Also the team is not very comfortable with git init, commit etc. So would like to make it easier for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), which is available free for online reading, has a [great chapter on Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) that should help clarify the options available and what you need to do to make them work. I would recommend a careful review of the chapter before you decide on servers, protocols, etc.

Comment: Link for the chapter doesn't work anymore, so not possible to "read" the solution

Comment: Fixed; I updated the links just now. (Normally I'd prefer to write good summaries of the answer and not just link to an external source, but this is such an open-ended question with a lot of facets, so the link really is the best I could do!)