# Linking a single file from another git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, repository

How do you link a **single file** from another git repository to your own repository?  I don't want the full repository, just a single file.  Using `git submodule` seems like the right route to go, but it wants to grab the whole thing.

Comment: Although it's not linking, git archive can be helpful for getting one or more files from another git repo, e.g. `git archive --format=tar --remote=your_chef_git_repo_uri HEAD: some_file another_file | tar -x`

Comment: For the record, a newer question seems to provide an answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844542/git-symbolic-link-to-file/27770463#27770463

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Considering that the unit of work for git is a repository (or more precisely a repository *content*), I don't think you can easily integrate one file.

If you don't need its history, you could consider simply copy it in your repo.
But if you do need the history, then some `git filter-branch` (as in "[git: How to split off library from project? filter-branch, subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403715/git-how-to-split-off-library-from-project-filter-branch-subtree)") are in order. That seems a lot of effort for just one file though.

In theory, "[git: symlink/reference to a file in an external repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770463/6309)" suggests a solution combining submodule and symlink.
(from [Pavel Šimerda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876370/pavel-%C5%A0imerda))

```
$ git submodule add /url/submodule/<reponame>
$ ln -s <reponame>/path/to/<linked_file>
$ git add .gitmodules <linked_file>
$ git commit -m "add a symbolic link to <linked_file> with the respective submodule"
```

Since 2011 (original answer above), [Gavriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661589/gavriel) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597748/linking-a-single-file-from-another-git-repository/7597867#comment83181335_7597867) that:

> - When I checkout the main repo, the linked file is not a symlink, but instead the file content is "`<reponame>/path/to/<linked_file>`". 
>     In other words git commits the symlink's target as file content
> - But the basic idea works.
>     I use "`submodule/path/to/file`" instead of "`file`" and it works

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I checkout the main repo, the linked file is not a symlink, but instead the file content is "<reponame>/path/to/<linked_file>". In other words git commits the symlink's  target as file content

Comment: @Gavriel OK, it might have changed since 6 years ago.

Comment: But the basic idea works. I use "submodule/path/to/file" instead of "file" and it works

Comment: @Gavriel can you post the procedure as an ANSWER?

Comment: @Zibri No need: I have included Gavriel's comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Gavriel I tried `git add .gitmodules <reponame>/<filename>` but git complain about `fatal: Pathspec '<reponame>/<filename>' is in submodule 'reponame'`. Did I understand your comment in a wrong way?