# Single dockerfiles GitHub repository + Docker Hub automated builds

Tags: git, docker, dockerhub

I would like to create a `dockerfiles` repository on GitHub to centralize all custom `Dockerfile`s I've created so far. I also would like to automatize builds of each image on Docker Hub, independently.

There is many repositories like this on GitHub :

- https://github.com/tianon/dockerfiles
- https://github.com/vimagick/dockerfiles

(I would not talk here about the most starred repository : https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles, because as you can see [on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jess), these are **not** automated builds)

### Wanted structure of `dockerfiles` repository

I'd like my `dockerfiles` GitHub repository have the following structure (branch `master`), based on GitHub repositories I mentioned above :

```
dockerfiles (GitHub repo)
    |- docker-image-1
        |- Dockerfile
    |- docker-image-2
        |- Dockerfile
    |- ...
```

### Docker Hub builds automation

#### Configuration

On Docker Hub, I could create 2 public automated builds : `docker-image-1` and `docker-image-2`, both referring to my `dockerfiles` GitHub repository, but with different *Build Settings* (in fact, only *Dockerfile Location* differs) :

- for `docker-image-1` :

  - *Type* : Branch
  - *Name* : master
  - *Dockerfile Location* : **/docker-image-1/**
  - *Docker Tag Name* : latest
- for `docker-image-2` :

  - *Type* : Branch
  - *Name* : master
  - *Dockerfile Location* : **/docker-image-2/**
  - *Docker Tag Name* : latest

#### Drawbacks

With this configuration, **all images** will be rebuilt if a push on `master` branch is made (even if there is only 1 `Dockerfile` concerned by the push and *Dockerfile Location*s are different). I've checked, it seems to be configured like this for [vimagick's repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick). But I don't think it's the right way (if I'm wrong, tell me).

Of course, in *Build Settings* of each automated build, I could disable option "*When active, builds will happen automatically on pushes*" to avoid this, but I'll have to trigger each build manually depending on what `Dockerfile` I've updated (not automatic).

### Improve automation?

Solutions I see to improve automation are :

1. separate each `Dockerfile` in its **own GitHub repository**. No more `dockerfiles` repository, so each one have its own workflow
2. use a single GitHub repository `dockerfiles`, but with **different branches** (one per Docker image). Each build could then be configured to be triggered only on the appropriate branch

With these solutions, problem is that I lost a **global overview** of all my `Dockerfile`s. I prefer the idea of a single repository with a single branch, but I don't want all images to be rebuilt on each push on this single branch.

If I'm choosing solution 1, I don't know if `git` can help me to keep a single repository `dockerfiles` referencing all my repositories, like :

```
 dockerfiles (GitHub repo)
    |- docker-image-1 -> link to https://github.com/norbjd/docker-image-1
        |- Dockerfile
    |- docker-image-2 -> link to https://github.com/norbjd/docker-image-2
        |- Dockerfile
```

It would then be easier to clone the whole project and do Pull Requests (since some images are related : updating `docker-image-1/Dockerfile` could lead to update `docker-image-2/Dockerfile`). I've read about Git submodules and subtrees, but I don't know if these are appropriate here.

Maybe it's possible with a single repository, and it's just about finding the right Docker Hub Build Settings.

What are the best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are no best practices but things that work for you. As I see, both decisions 1.) and 2.) about the common repository `dockerfiles` are quite good in order to apply the Docker Hub automation, but I would recommend to complement them as you mention with `git submodules` or `git subtrees`. I would not enter into details about the Docker Hub automation, but on how to keep the common repository `dockerfiles`:

1.) You can separate the `Dockerfile` images in its **own GitHub repository**. Then in your `dockerfiles` I would recommend to use `git submodule`:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/norbjd/docker-image-1
git commit -m "Add docker-image-1 as submodule"
```

Unfortunately you cannot AFAIK select only one file using submodule, instead you have the link to the origin repo. You can have a look at [Linking a single file from another git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597748/linking-a-single-file-from-another-git-repository) and also [git: symlink/reference to a file in an external repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844542/git-symlink-reference-to-a-file-in-an-external-repository/27770463#27770463). But be careful with submodules because there are [well-known drawbacks](https://rufflewind.com/2017-02-21/quirks-with-submodules), if someone besides you wants to use it. I also put an example [here](https://github.com/carloscaverobarca/dockerfiles-submodule-example) to show you how it looks like.

2.) You can use **only one GitHub dockerfiles repository**, but then I would use `git subtree`. You can split your repo using subtree in different branches, keeping several modules organized with a quite clean tree.

```
git subtree split --prefix=docker-image-1 -b docker-image-1-subtree
```

Check [this post](https://tsh.io/blog/git-subtree-or-how-i-stopped-worrying-and-learned-to-love-external-dependencies/) for further information regarding subtrees. I did not have time to play around with `git subtree` to give you an example, but I guess you can get the point.

So, being purist I would not recommend the use of `git submodule` and I read a lot of people saying `git subtree` is awesome, so I would go for option 2.). But I am not a purist at all and separating the repos would ease the Docker Hub automation and also it is a CI principle, so go for the option that best adapts to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly `subtree`, the 2nd solution with 1 branch = 1 `Dockerfile` will remove the ability to see all `Dockerfile`s at a glance : to view/edit a specific Dockerfile, `checkout`ing the appropriate branch will be required. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct at a first glance (it is organized as a tree, so it is there) and AFAIK the Docker Hub integration is less automatic than with option 1

Comment: Great idea w.r.t. using submodules to manage individual Dockerhub repos. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I think I'm going to use the 1st solution (submodules), or the 2nd solution slightly modified to use individual repos instead of different branches with subtree. Thanks for the answer.