# Git strategy for a project with many independent modules

Tags: git

We are working on a project composed of about a dozen different modules. Each module is a small application per se (some of them are Rails apps, some are daemon services, etc.)

We are hesitating between 2 options:

1/ One git repo with one folder per module

2/ Several git repos (one per module)

Which approach is the best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One repo per module is usually best, especially if they can evolve and being tagged independently one from another.
This is akin to a [component-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735), and similar to what I proposed in "[Component based web project directory layout with git and symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896944/component-based-web-project-directory-layout-with-git-and-symlinkshttp://Component%20based%20web%20project%20directory%20layout%20with%20git%20and%20symlinks)".

But if you cannot make any change in one without having to modify another component (or several others), then and only then, one repo would make sense.
That would be called the "[system approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735)" in a "Component-driven development".
The other argument for one repo would be if all those components have only a few files in them (and not tens or hundreds of files).